# PHP и GreyScale

Tags: php

Есть ли в php стандартная функция для обесцвечивания изображения и автоматического сохранения в папку ?

Дело в том что  крайней мере я не нашёл 100% кроссбраузерного решения и может быть на php есть такое ?

Видел огромную кучу таких решений но они не работали в IE и так же в EDGE и так же в Midori и уже достала меня эта тема, я много заказов потерял из за этого.

Заказчики отдавали заказ другим исполнителям и они им делали но не кроссраузерно - это как бы не айс ,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://bubble.ro/How_to_convert_an_image_to_grayscale_using_PHP.html).

```
<?php 
    $source_file = "test_image.jpg";
    $im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($source_file); 
    $imgw = imagesx($im);
    $imgh = imagesy($im);
    for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
    {
            for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
            {
                    $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j); 
                    $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                    $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;
                    $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);
                    $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);
                    imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
            }
    }

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    ?>
```

Comment: посмотрел и проверил во всех броузерах - Greate !